# Cypher query to return one relationship per type in a neo4j graph

Tags: types, neo4j, cypher, relationship

Is there a Cypher query to return a single relationship of each relationship type in a graph?

For example, I have a graph containing 5 relationships typed `TYPE_X`, 10 relationships typed `TYPE_Y`, and 1 relationship typed `TYPE_Z`. The query would return 3 relationships:

```
()-[r1:TYPE_X]->()
()-[r2:TYPE_Y]->()
()-[r3:TYPE_Z]->()
```

It doesn't matter which `TYPE_X` relationship is returned as `r1`. Ideally, the query wouldn't have to scan every relationship, it would just return a single arbitrary relationship for each type.

This query would be useful for interrogating relationship types and their properties in the interactive browser.

---

#### Update based on @christophe-willemsen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36005955/4651668).

I used the following query:

```
MATCH ()-[r]->()
RETURN type(r) AS rel_type, collect(r)[0] AS example
```

to generate the following [visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaelA.png) with one relationship for every type:

[image: rephetio: one relationship per type]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is pretty easy, you just have to aggregate on the relationship type :

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
RETURN type(r), collect(r)[0] AS oneRel
```

-

```
REL3    (34)-[20:REL3]->(35)
REL2    (18)-[12:REL2]->(19)
REL1    (6)-[6:REL1]->(7)
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question with the visualization I produced using this query. For reference, this query first performed an `AllNodesScan` which hit every node and second performed an `Expand(All)` which hit every relationship. Using the 2.3.2 cost planner, the query took 9 seconds on [my hetnet](http://thinklab.com/p/rephetio) with 50 thousand nodes and 3 million relationships.

Answer (score 0):

## Selecting one random relationship per type

In Neo4j 3.0.1, I've been using the following command to select a single random relationship per type.

```
MATCH ()-[r]->()
WITH type(r) AS rel_type, collect(r) AS rels
WITH rel_type, rels, toInt(rand() * size(rels)) AS idx
RETURN rel_type, rels[idx] AS example
```

The is based on [@christophe-willemsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36005955/4651668) with the addition of random index lookup on the relationship collections.